# Umbraco 7.7.3 Programmatically set password for a new User

Tags: umbraco7

I am programmatically creating users (not members!) in umbraco 7.7.3 using the **UmbracoContext.Application.Services.UserService** like this :

```
user = userService.CreateUserWithIdentity(someMailAddress, someMailAddress);
user.AddGroup((UserGroup)someGroup);
user.StartMediaId = someMediaId;
user.StartContentId = SomeContentId;
userService.Save(user);
userService.SavePassword(user,password);
```

The users are correctly created.

I am not using the method **userService.CreateWithIdentity** because I need to provide the hashed password, and I don't know how to hash the default password I want to give to those new users.

I'm trying to use userService.SavePassword() method but I am getting and exception saying : "*This provider does not support manually changing the password*"

I have read somewhere that I should set the attribute **allowManuallyChangingPassword** in the UmbracoMembershipProvider element to *true* in the web.config, but it is not working for me.

Any help would be highly appreciated : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UmbracoMembershipProvider` refers to Members, not Users, so in this case, you should change this value for `UsersMembershipProvider`.

You could also try to set `RawPasswordValue` property for newly created user:

`user.RawPasswordValue = (Membership.Providers["UsersMembershipProvider"] as UsersMembershipProvider).HashPasswordForStorage(password);`

Comment: Great ! Putting allowManuallyChangingPassword to true for UsersMembershipProvider saved my day. Thanks a lot.